# How to Disable Text selection on firefox in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using this CSS to disable text selection. It works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox

```
*.e-pdfviewer-pageCanvas {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none !important;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

*.e-pdfviewer-pageCanvas * {
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -khtml-user-select: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -o-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the following code you can disable text selection in the entire webpage, **except `inputs` and `textareas`**:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].onselectstart = function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName != "INPUT" && e.target.nodeName != "TEXTAREA") {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Alternatively, if you want to disable text selection **completely** you can use this code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].onselectstart = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
};
```

If you want to disable text selection only for the elements having the class **`.e-pdfviewer-pageCanvas`** you can use:

```
var pdfviewer = document.getElementsByClassName("e-pdfviewer-pageCanvas");

for (var i = 0; i < pdfviewer.length; i++) {
    pdfviewer[i].onselectstart = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };
};
```

---

### **[EDIT]:**

If none of the aforementioned solved your issue, use the following code in your HTML **`<body>`** or the element you want to disable text selection for specifically:

```
<body onselectstart = "return false;" style = "-moz-user-select: none;">...</body>
```

**Or in JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].onselectstart = function(e) {return false};

document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.mozUserSelect = "none";
```

Comment: The Entire canvas gets selected while selecting the text ,i have used onselectstart and also css but also the selection appears in Firefox only

Comment: Doesn't this also disable selection of content in text/input fields

Comment: No, because I use this line **`e.target.nodeName != "INPUT" && e.target.nodeName != "TEXTAREA"`**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple jQuery plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    disableSelection : function() {
        this.each(function() {
            this.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
            this.unselectable = "on";
            jQuery(this).css({
                 '-moz-user-select': 'none'
                ,'-o-user-select': 'none'
                ,'-khtml-user-select': 'none'
                ,'-webkit-user-select': 'none'
                ,'-ms-user-select': 'none'
                ,'user-select': 'none'
            });
        });
    }
});

$('.e-pdfviewer-pageCanvas').disableSelection();
```